# A palavra “judiar” é ofensiva?

Tags: origem-histórica, mudanças-históricas

Estava no dicionário, pesquisando *judiação*, e eis que vejo ela é ofensiva! E o Houaiss diz que isso vem da “antiga tradição antissemita de origem europeia”. Sempre a usei e nunca percebi nela ofensa alguma.

A palavra *judiar* já foi ou é ofensiva algures? E por que ela é ou era considerada ofensiva?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A própria pergunta já indica a resposta: a palavra *judiar* “vem da ‘antiga tradição antissemita de origem europeia’”. Etimologicamente, *judiar* vem de *judeu* ou *judio*. As aceções ofensivas são as 2 e 3 do Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002):

> **judiar** […] **1** *int.* m. q. *JUDAIZAR* (’adoptar práticas judaicas’)  **2** *t.i.* (1789) tratar com escárnio; zombar <*judiar com a infelicidade alheia*> **3** *t.i.* (1881) tratar mal, física ou moralmente; atormentar, maltratar <*tem um alma perversa, judia com os animais*> <*judiava dele provocando-lhe ciúmes*> […] ꙩ ETIM *judeu* + -*ar* […]

Este uso de *judiar* nasceu do antissemitismo e implica que aqueles comportamentos — escarnecer, maltratar — são típicos dos judeus. É natural que um judeu se sinta ofendido por isto, independentemente das intenções do falante.

Na mesma tradição, além de *judiação* mencionada na pergunta, temos também [*judiaria* (Priberam)](https://dicionario.priberam.org/judiaria), que além de ’bairro de judeus’ significa também ’crueldade, travessura’; e mesmo [*judeu* (Priberam)](https://dicionario.priberam.org/judeu), ’que faz judiarias, perverso, travesso; agiota’.

Estes usos vem na linha duma tradição realmente antiga de acusações injuriosas aos judeus.  Desde o início do cristianismo, os judeus, nascidos e por nascer, foram acusados de serem coletivamente culpados da morte de Jesus ([Jewish deicide; Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_deicide)). Isto vem da passagem em [Mateus 27, 24-25](https://www.bibliaonline.com.br/acf/mt/27): quando Pilatos lava as mãos e se declara inocente da morte de Jesus, os judeus respondem, “o seu sangue caia sobre nós e sobre os nossos filhos”. Durante a Idade Média, os judeus foram ainda acusados de matarem inocentes e usar o seu sangue em rituais religiosos ([Libelo de sange, Wikipédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libelo_de_sangue), de profanarem a hóstia, que a doutrina católica considera ser o corpo de Cristo ([Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profana%C3%A7%C3%A3o_da_h%C3%B3stia)) e de causar a peste negra através do envenenamento de poços ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persecution_of_Jews_during_the_Black_Death)).

Comment: Muito obrigado, Jacinto. Ainda estou espantado que *judiar* vem de judeu.

Comment: @Schilive, no Houaiss que tu consultaste diz, não? Eu na minha infância ouvi a suíte completa, *judiar, judiaria, judeu (’que faz judiarias’)*, que torna clara a origem. Fui várias vezes acusado de ser judeu. Mas tudo isto foi caindo em desuso por cá.

Comment: Jacinto, diz, fala que vem do castelhano *judio* e assumi que tinha o mesmo significado de *judiar*, nas acepções 2 e 3. Aqui vejo mais se usando para *maltratar* como tormento, como na aqui famosíssima música Asa Branca: “Eu preguntei' a Deus do céu, uai/Por que tamanha judiação?”, ou «para de judiar do amiguinho!». E, como se muito comummente usa para falar com Deus, achei estranhíssimo ser ofensivo.

Comment: @Schilive, *judio* também existe em português. E o feminino de *judeu*, tal como de *judio*, é *judia*.

Comment: Jacinto, não sabia disso. Obrigado. Vou apagar este comentário.

Comment: @Schilive, ah, então tu é que presumiste que era castelhano? O Houaiss não diz que é?

Comment: Jacinto, o Houaiss disse que era castelhano, eu assumi o significado de *judio* em castelhano.

Comment: @Schilive, pois, isso é muito estranho. O meu Houaiss (2002) traz *judia*, mas não *judio* (e diz que *judiar* vem de *judeu*), mas vários outros dicionários trazem *judio*; dizem que é popular. O castelhano *judiar* só significa *judaizar*.

Comment: Jacinto, eu uso o [Houaiss on-line](https://houaiss.uol.com.br/corporativo/apps/uol_www), então, talvez tenha sido atualização? pois, o on-line é atualizado — agora ele até fala, ou tenta. A Infopédia diz que *judiar* vem de *judio*, e ela e o Priberam dizem que *judio* vem do castelhano *judio*, mas o Priberam também diz que *judiar* vem de *judeu*, e a Infopédia diz que *judia* vem de *judio*. Parece-me haver controvérsia na origem.

Comment: @Schilive  Na minha região (sudeste do Brasil) é muito comum o uso do verbo judiar por pessoas que nem pensam haver alguma relação da palavra com o povo judeu.  Usam sem pensar em ofensa, da mesma forma que usamos uma série de outras palavras que potencialmente podem ser acusadas de racistas ou preconceituosas: o desinfetante **creolina**, **denegrir** a imagem de alguém, fazer uma lista **negra**, soltar uma "**cabeça de nego**", uma bela "**mulata**", amanhã é **dia de branco** etc.  Todas essas são palavras que, se analisadas quanto a origem, seriam consideradas ofensivas.

Answer (score 3):

Decidi consultar os potenciais atingidos.

Contactei algumas instituições lusófonas ligadas ao judaísmo e repassei nossa pergunta:

> A palavra “judiar” é ofensiva?

As instituições foram:

- [Confederação Israelita do Brasil](https://www.conib.org.br/proposito/)
- [Congregação Judaica do Brasil](http://www.cjb.org.br/)
- [Comunidade Israelita de Lisboa](https://cilisboa.org/)
- [Museu do Holocausto de Curitiba](https://www.museudoholocausto.org.br/)

Apenas a última me respondeu:

> Sim! Há alguns materiais sobre o tema!

Se referindo a [este vídeo](https://www.instagram.com/tv/CEZ0xnch-F2/) divulgado no Instagram (encontrado pelo Schilive) defendendo o abandono da palavra "judiar".

E, por último, criei uma enquete, obviamente sem valor estatístico, numa página do Facebook relacionada, em que a maioria declarou considerar a palavra ofensiva:

[image]

Em retrospecto, embora talvez seja óbvio, eu certamente deveria ter mencionado também que a maioria das pessoas faz uso da palavra sem consciência de sua etimologia; é possível que essa omissão tenha influenciado os resultados.

Portanto, não temos nem a palavra de nenhuma instituição representativa, nem tampouco uma pesquisa de opinião representativa — mas os indícios apontam que quem quiser considerar os sentimentos dos judeus talvez queira evitar usar a palavra "judiar".

Answer (score 1):

Concordo como o @Jacinto mas parece-me que há ainda algumas trivialidades a considerar:

#### Contexto

(1) Uma palavra em si não é ofensiva. Só passa a ser mediante o uso que lhe é dado. (2) Convém ver quem ofende e quem é o ofendido (que ofensas pretendo).

Ex **Insulto de Classe** (usarei judeu mas generaliza para as outras classe):

1. Chamar judeu a um judeu é um elogio! (também elogia se o orador gostar dos judeus).
2. Chamar judeu a um "não judeu", se a sociedade admitir
   que é insultuoso é uma tri-ofensa.

- orador insulta ao "não judeu" => imp("tu és tão mau como os judeus")
- orador insulta a classe abstrata dos judeus => imp("e os judeus são muito maus")
- sociedade insulta os judeus => imp("judeu é um insulto")

#### Etimologias e critalizações de significado

Os ptbr usam muito o verbo **judiar** (=maltratar ligeiro, irritar) os ptpt usam bastante o **(não)? fazer judiarias**
(Ex: não faças judiarias ao cão = não maltrates o cão).

Ambas as expressões, com o uso e o tempo, embora derivando de preconceitos, ganharam já uma semântica nova (diferente do seu avó preconceituoso, racista).

Em minha opinião "judiar" e "não fazer judiarias", no seu uso habitual"
já criaram identidade própria suficientemente forte para não constituírem ofensa ao povo Judeu.

#### Outros casos similares

- Tu és um burro! - para além da intencional ofensa ao interlocutor, contém um implícito (e injusto) preconceito acerca da pouco inteligência dos burros. Muitos dos insultos seguem fenómenos análogos.

Comment: Re: "embora derivando de preconceitos, ganharam já uma semântica nova". Entendo o raciocínio, e concordo que ele válido para, e.g., aplicar a "presunção de boas intenções" (eu mesmo só agora fiquei sabendo da etimologia de "judiar"), mas não concordo que o caráter ofensivo tenha de todo desaparecido — só quem poderia se manifestar nesse sentido seriam representantes da comunidade judaica lusófona.

Comment: Aqui no site usamos pt-PT para designar o português europeu, e pt-BR para o brasileiro. (os falantes de pt-PT, os falantes de pt-BR)

Comment: @stafusa: repara que eu escrevi "Em minha opinião". Se vocês pretendem uma postura normativa, politicamente correcta, a lista de palavras proibidas seria infindável! Já agora algumas ofensas: **Barbaridades** = ofente os descendentes dos Celtas, Alanos, visigodos = Europa inteira; Quase todos os insultos **Cretino** - etim(cristão); **Imbecil** -- etim(deficiente fisico que precisa de uma bengala para se ter de pé); **Parvo** -- etim(pequeno); **farisaismos**; **denegrir**

Comment: @Centaurus, foi tambem a notação que eu fui usando.

Comment: @JJoao Não é proibido ofender, nem há uma lista oficial de palavras proibidas (embora plataformas como o SE naturalmente tenham suas normas, mas não é disso que trata a pergunta). Contudo, _se alguém prefere_ evitar ofender (quando possível, e dentro de limites razoáveis, afinal tudo é potencialmente ofensivo), então penso (também estou apenas dando minha opinião) que cabe consultar os potenciais ofendidos. Inclusive já fiz um pequena consulta e, quando tiver uma resposta, posto aqui.

Comment: @JJoao Sobre a lista infindável, concordo que é inviável e indesejável. Por outro lado, enquanto realmente existe uma discussão sobre palavras como, e.g., "denegrir", não creio que haja muitos usuários de bengala que se sintam atingidos pela palavra "imbecil", ou pessoas que considerem preconceituoso usar o termo "barbaridade" — é preciso evitar cair na falácia do [declive escorregadio](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fal%C3%A1cia#Bola_de_neve).

Comment: @stafusa, (> cair na falácia...) nos meus comentários as falácias são intensionais, assumidas e apreciadas!. (> que se sintam atingidos pela palavra...) nada é garantido   Na assembleia ptpt o partido político PAN propôs a alteração / remoção de manuais escolares de provérbios e expressões que pudessem ofender animais. Ex: pela boca morre o peixe, gato escaldado de água fria tem medo; "fulano é um camelo"

Comment: @JJoao Ofender animais? OK, essa eu não teria esperado.